# Set width and height of graphic made using ggplot, grid, and gridExtra

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, r-grid, gridextra

If I have a graphic composed of several plots, say three plots arranged vertically. This is a gtable object and can be drawn to the page with:

```
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(plot)
```

However I see that the plot in my RStudio is 'smushed up' as in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see in the bottom right corner it is squashed and the titles overlap with other elements of the graphic.

If I hit zoom and view the plot it is a lot bigger:

[image]

Now I know, that if I were to export my gtable plot using pdf() or png() and such devices, I can set a width and a height, and so just make it big enough such that the plot is not squashed.

However, instead of one of those graphic devices, I would like to use `export.grid`, from the gridSVG package to save it to an SVG file. But if I do

```
gridSVG::export.grid(plot)
```

Then the SVG file exported looks squashed as it does in the RStudio plot window.
So my question is, how can I manipulate the dimensions of the graphic so it is drawn to SVG without it looking squashed? I draw the plot initially with `grid.newpage` and `grid.draw`, I wonder perhaps I have to specify some size of the page or drawing using grid.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: `export.grid()` isn't an exported function in the CRAN version of gridSVG ([link to gridSVG manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridSVG/gridSVG.pdf)).

Comment: Do you have objections to using `grDevices::svg()` which would work just like `png()` or `pdf()` and has width and height arguments?

Comment: I shall try it and see how it does. I think I remember it not working so great for me though.

Comment: Would it help to pop out a new graphics window with `dev.new()` that can be freely re-sized?